# Create a folder with unlimited revision numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up a new data location in VBA and I want to store all my results and all runs of these results.

So, for example, I  create a folder named as yesterday 20190403. however I now want to store in a subfolder called 'v0001' however if that's already there I want to be 'v0002' and so on.

My issue is I don't know how to create the folder with this iteration, and I also don't know how to find the last version of this folder to save files down in later. As it will be a separate process. For example, I am running later in the day, I have 2 questions:

1) How do I know create a folder that will iterate onto version number. i.e v0001 to v0016 has been made, thus I should make v0017. 
2) I want to save to the latest version number, how would I know that the last version is v0017 and I should save it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function returns the last version of the subfolder. When you set the 2nd parameter to `True`, it will create a new folder with the next free number.

```
Function GetLatestFolder(BaseFolder As String, createNew As Boolean) As String

    Dim dirName As String, i As Long

    If Right(BaseFolder, 1) <> "\" Then BaseFolder = BaseFolder & "\"

    For i = 1 To 9999
        dirName = Format(i, "V0000")
        If Dir(BaseFolder & dirName, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            ' This folder doesn't exist.
            ' If requested, created it
            If createNew Then
                 MkDir BaseFolder & dirName
                 GetLatestFolder = dirName
            Else
                ' Return the folder with last found number
                GetLatestFolder = Format(i - 1, "V0000")
            End If
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Note that there is currently no error handling, so if no subfolder exists at all, it will return an invalid path "v0000" and if the number of folders reaches 9999, it will return nothing.

Comment: Both answers are great, but I ended up implementing the latter as it has the dual functionality, thanks both. Great answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a function that would find the max version folder in a folder that you send to it:

```
Function findLastVersion(versionFolder As String) As String
    ''Reference Windows Script Host Object Model in Tools>>References

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim folderRoot As Folder
    Dim folderSub As Folder
    Dim maxVersionFolder As String

    Set folderRoot = fso.GetFolder(versionFolder)

    For Each folderSub In folderRoot.SubFolders
        If folderSub.Name Like "v*" And (folderSub.Name > maxVersionFolder Or maxVersionFolder = "") Then maxVersionFolder = folderSub.Name
    Next

    findLastVersion = maxVersionFolder
End Function
```

You can call it like:

```
Dim maxVersion As String
maxVersion = findLastVersion("C:\some\folder\")
```

And assuming that is the folder where you keep these version numbered subdirectories, that will spit out the max version. You can use this `fso` object to create directories as well.